# Assign a value to an object's property via map

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, assign

i have an object with country codes and country names like this:

```
countries = {'CA': {name: Canada}, 'GR': {name: Greece}, 'SG': {name: Singapore}}
```

Then i have another array like this:

```
markets = ["CA", "GR", "SG"]
```

Then i want to create an array of objects for every instance of the markets array with with this shape:
{label:..., value:....}
So i'm writing

```
const martOptions = markets.map((i) => {
 return {label: i, value: i}
})
```

But for the label i don't want to assign CA or GR. I want somehow to find the name of the country in the countries object and add it to the label so as to have something like this:
`{label: Canada, value: CA} and not {label: CA, value: CA}`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You just need to refer back to the `countries` object to get the name associated with the current country code:

```js
const countries = {'CA': {name: 'Canada'}, 'GR': {name: 'Greece'}, 'SG': {name: 'Singapore'}}

const markets = ["CA", "GR", "SG"]

const martOptions = markets.map((i) => ({label: countries[i].name, value: i}))

console.log(martOptions)
```

Note that `countries[i].name` would give you an error if there was a code in the `markets` array that didn't exist in the `countries` object.

(Note also that if you put it in parentheses you can directly return the new object without needing the `{ return ... }` structure in the arrow function.)